# On NUC6i5SYK Ubuntu Linux 15.10 display goes to sleep immediately after splash screen appears

Tags: boot, grub2, graphics, intel-graphics, intel-nuc

I installed Ubuntu Linux 15.10 from a USB thumb drive on my NUC6i5SYK.  I had to add `nomodeset` to get the LiveCD environment to boot, as the display would sleep if I didn't (as described here: [Intel NUC NUC5i5RYH - Boot - only mouse pointer appears (Xubuntu 14.04, 14.10) - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591992/intel-nuc-nuc5i5ryh-boot-only-mouse-pointer-appears-xubuntu-14-04-14-10) and other places).  I was able to successfully install Ubuntu from the LiveCD environment.  Now I see the same issue with the installed version, i.e. it gets to the purple background and the display immediately sleeps.  I'm connecting to a Dell U3415W via mini-DisplayPort.

I can boot the recovery mode GRUB menu item and then select resume the normal boot and it appears to work fine.  Yet it consistently puts the display to sleep with a normal boot.

Things I've tried that haven't resolved the issue:

1. Adding **i915.preliminary_hw_support=1** to GRUB boot configuration, per [Early Intel Skylake Linux Users May Run Into A Silly Issue - Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-SKL-Prelim-Support) and other sources
2. Updating Intel Linux Graphics drivers to latest Ubuntu release [Intel Graphics Installer for Linux* 1.2.1 | 01.org](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.1)
3. Installing Kernel 4.3 drivers - [No version of Ubuntu can be installed with any Skylake 6th generation Intel processor - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691216/no-version-of-ubuntu-can-be-installed-with-any-skylake-6th-generation-intel-proc)
4. Installing Kernel 4.4 drivers with the missing Skylake firmware file [Installing 4.4 rc7 kernel yields i915 module not available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717338/installing-4-4-rc7-kernel-yields-i915-module-not-available)

Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to get it booted into Ubuntu using `nomodeset`.  Would still like to get the graphics drivers working properly.

Comment: When I connected via HDMI instead of mini-DisplayPort, Ubuntu booted normally.  Sound was working as well, which wasn't working with the DisplayPort interface, in addition to the issue described above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues as you. I have a Dell U3415w monitor, and when I disabled DP1.2 in the OSD, it worked fine. Both picture and sound.